# flink cluster params - how to set

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Im doing some proof-of-concept work with **Flink** and have gotten to the point where I want to try my various jobs (topologies?) on a 4 node cluster.

Machines:

- 32 core
- 96g Gb RAM

The topologies vary from 3 to 6 'tasks' (workers? bolt-analogs?). I'm hoping that someone here can offer some suggested settings. Specifically:

- taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: set this to # of cores?
- taskmanager.heap.mb: "This value should be as large as possible." 96Gb? Really?
- parallelism.default: tried setting this to 30. Got this error<sup>1</sup>.
- parallelization.degree.default: I tried upping this value but it didn't seem to have any effect. Tasks always show '1' for parallelism.
- any other settings that people have found useful / interesting?

One task in particular: reading from **Kafka** where topic in question has 6 partitions. From each of these partitions I want to read, aggregate and write to **Cassandra**. When I implemented this job in **Storm** it had 6 bolts to read the data and several times as many to write. (IE 6 read, 18 write)

If **Flink** gets adopted by my company each machine will run numerous, simultaneous jobs. How will the config params alter under such a circumstance?

FWIW: cluster is v1.0-SNAPSHOT.

---

EDIT: [This](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/config.html#configuring-taskmanager-processing-slots) seems useful.

<sup>1</sup> "Insufficient number of network buffers: required 30, but only 8 available. The total number of network buffers is currently set to 2048." Does this mean that 2000 buffers are being used when nothing is happening?

Comment: Concerning the number of network buffers: These are reserved when a streaming dataflow program is submitted for execution. They are the minimum needed to successfully execute a program, so this is basically a safety check at the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple sources that will help you to set the correct setting (see below)

To address your questions right away:

- taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: set this to # of cores?
  **yes**
- taskmanager.heap.mb: "This value should be as large as possible." 96Gb? Really?
  **bacially yes, but it depends** If you deploy Flink manually in a cluster, it is assumed that Flink is the only system running. It would be a waste if you do not make this parameter as large as possible. For a shared setup with other systems, you might want to consider to use YARN. On the ohter hand running in standalone cluster mode, you might want to leave some memory for the OS and if you know that there a other components running, you might not assign all memory to Flink. However, as Flink manages the memory internally, you should avoided to have unused memory.
- parallelism.default: tried setting this to 30. Got this error.
  **look at the following configuration paramters:** `taskmanager.network.numberOfBuffers` and `taskmanager.network.bufferSizeInBytes` (also have a look here http://www.slideshare.net/FlinkForward/fabian-hueske-juggling-with-bits-and-bytes?ref=http://flink-forward.org/?post_type=session, here http://de.slideshare.net/robertmetzger1/apache-flink-hands-on and here https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDX4T_cnKjD3F7oRSov8hT21rXx1SyXf8)
- parallelization.degree.default: I tried upping this value but it didn't seem to have any effect. Tasks always show '1' for parallelism.
  **If I am not wrong, this parameter got replaced by** `parallelism.default`

check out this links for more background info:

- https://flink.apache.org/faq.html#what-is-the-parallelism-how-do-i-set-it
- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/config.html#common-options
- https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/05/11/Juggling-with-Bits-and-Bytes.html

And general FAQ, the Flink Blog, and Flink Forward talks:

- https://flink.apache.org/faq.html
- https://flink.apache.org/blog/
- http://flink-forward.org/?post_type=session